# Grok pattern to remove "ms" from log string and convert to INT

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, grok

first time long time.

I have this log message:

`2022/05/04 09:24:08 INTERESTING UpdateStatus: active: 45 waiting: 0 connections: 91 max dbcmd queue length: 3 max dbcmd response time: 19ms cmds processed: 6 nacks: 0 nresent: 0`

I have this grok pattern to parse it:

`%{DATE} %{TIME} %{WORD:log_level} %{WORD:update_status}: active: %{INT:active} waiting: %{INT:waiting} connections: %{INT:connections} max dbcmd queue length: %{NUMBER:max_dbcmd_queue_length} max dbcmd response time: %{WORD:max_dbcmd_response_time} cmds processed: %{NUMBER:cmds_processed} nacks: %{NUMBER:nacks} nresent: %{NUMBER:nresent}`

All is ok and great except for one thing,

This value I would like to extract the response time and graph the int (19).

`max dbcmd response time: 19ms`

But the only way I can get grok to be happy is to make it a WORD because of the "ms".

`max dbcmd response time: %{WORD:max_dbcmd_response_time}`

I really want 19 to be an INT and I can't figure out how to remove or ignore the "ms" tagged to the end of the number "19ms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INT` but then you need to add `ms` or `\w*` after the pattern part:

```
%{INT:max_dbcmd_response_time}ms
%{INT:max_dbcmd_response_time}\w*
```

The full pattern:

```
%{DATE} %{TIME} %{WORD:log_level} %{WORD:update_status}: active: %{INT:active} waiting: %{INT:waiting} connections: %{INT:connections} max dbcmd queue length: %{NUMBER:max_dbcmd_queue_length} max dbcmd response time: %{INT:max_dbcmd_response_time}ms cmds processed: %{NUMBER:cmds_processed} nacks: %{NUMBER:nacks} nresent: %{NUMBER:nresent}
```

Or

```
%{DATE} %{TIME} %{WORD:log_level} %{WORD:update_status}: active: %{INT:active} waiting: %{INT:waiting} connections: %{INT:connections} max dbcmd queue length: %{NUMBER:max_dbcmd_queue_length} max dbcmd response time: %{INT:max_dbcmd_response_time}\w* cmds processed: %{NUMBER:cmds_processed} nacks: %{NUMBER:nacks} nresent: %{NUMBER:nresent}
```